# Unable to install theme recommended plugins on Multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite, themes, errors

I uploaded and activated the theme on my multisite network successfully. After this, I was trying to install the plugins that come bundled with the theme but when I clicked on install, it is showing this error.

[image]

Here's a small gif of the error

[image]

Comment: Are you really trying to install a theme as a plugin?

Comment: No. I already installed the theme by uploading it in themes page. This is a required plugin(ZoTheme) to import demo content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing new. 
The only problem you have is with the access rights. 
Try to work as super admin.  All the messages starting with `'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.'` do have `!can_edit_network( $details->site_id )` condition. So you don't have the access right.

```
if ( !can_edit_network( $details->site_id ) )
    wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.' ), 403 );
```

Work on your access rights.

Comment: I think you're right. I just had a look at the user roles and I saw that I have not any privileges on that website.

Comment: Please ✓ this for the others. :) @Rahul

Comment: Install the plugin manually can be another solution, you'll just need to activated it for the network.

Comment: @Benoti You are right, I tried this but there were some plugins(talking about the plugins which came with theme) that can only be installed with in the theme options(you can see that in the GIF I linked in the question).

Comment: Ok, I thought that the plugin was available on the WordPress repositary. Did you try to access to the url directly and download it ?

Comment: No it isn't available externally. It is patched up with the theme.